# Routing issues with nginx ingress controller and basic django app

Tags: django, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

EDIT: I rewrote the question with a fully reproducible example.

I have a sample Django app with the base getting started https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/, that is, there are two paths `/admin` and `/polls`.

If I deploy the app using NodePort, I can access both paths without issues. However, I haven't managed to do the same with Nginx ingress controller. I have tried several combinations of annotations and paths to no avail.

So, assume this yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: django
  name: django
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: django
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: django
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: "ay0o/django-ingress:latest"
        name: django
# ---
# apiVersion: v1
# kind: Service
# metadata:
#   name: django
# spec:
#   ports:
#   - nodePort: 31000
#     port: 8000
#     targetPort: 8000
#   selector:
#     app: django
#   type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: django
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
  selector:
    app: django
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /django
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: django
            port:
              number: 8000
```

when I use NodePort, `http://localhost:31000/admin` and `http://localhost:31000/polls` work fine.

when I use Ingress, `http://localhost/django` returns a 404 from django (because the path is neither admin nor polls), but `http://localhost/django/admin` and `http://localhost/django/polls` return a 404 from nginx, meaning the ingress is not properly routing.

so, what should I change so that `http://localhost/django/admin` and `http://localhost/django/polls` will not return 404?

Comment: Hello @Ay0. Could you please check the Controller's and your app's logs? It would be useful to see what happens there actually. Please edit your question by providing that info.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor edited the whole question with a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that it's not possible to use path-based Ingress for a Django app, probably due to something related to Django's internals.

Every example out there uses host-based rules, and indeed, that just work. For example, the Ingress above can be changed to the following, and it will work.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: django
            port:
              number: 8000
```

If anyone come up with a solution using path-based routing, feel free to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't has both of them managing the routing path. You have to choose one of them. This is because Ingress was built to routing the traffic through cluster for microservices. If you want to really use it, you have to split your application on two separate services that accepts requests just at /. And let the routing with Ingress. Look at this page:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout

If you don't want to change your application or if it's just for testing purposes. The way it's deploy a Ingress with two rules:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /admin
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: django
            port: 
              number: 80
      - path: /polls
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: django
            port: 
              number: 80
```

This will accept the requests on both of the path's.